# How to execute a control-flow statement in MySQL with user-defined variables?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to execute a simple control-flow statement in MySQL with user-defined variables.

The following are my SQL query:

```
mysql> SET @something=2;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET @z=1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> IF @z = 1 THEN SET @something=1;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF @z = 1 THEN SET @something=1' at line 1
mysql> select @z, @something;
+------+------------+
| @z   | @something |
+------+------------+
|    1 |          2 |
+------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

My control statement is saying SQL syntax error. But when I check the syntax [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/if.html), it seems correct. My guess is because it is of the user-defined variable but could not find any similar issue or example execution.

Anyone knows how to properly execute this SQL query?
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Control flow statements can only be used in stored programs, not in queries.

Comment: I think you can only use `IF` this way inside something like a stored proc.  If you are planning to use some dynamic SQL in a query, proc, function, etc., then you might want to show us the real problem.

Comment: You can use a control flow function instead: `SET @something = IF(@z = 1, 1, @something);`

Comment: It is prefer way to use control statement in function,trigger,store proc.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks. I'll try the control flow function for my use case